# Oracle SQL. Get Dates between two dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with two date columns, how can get the dates between these two dates and list them one by one.  Here is the test script:

```
CREATE TABLE t1
   AS
      SELECT DATE '2020-1-31' AS startdate,
             DATE '2020-2-3' AS enddate
      FROM dual
      UNION
      SELECT DATE '2020-2-27' AS startdate,
             DATE '2020-3-3' AS enddate
      FROM dual;

SELECT *
FROM t1;


DROP TABLE t1;
```

The result set I am expecting is:

[image]

How should I do the query?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
SQL> select * From t1;

STARTDATE  ENDDATE
---------- ----------
01/31/2020 02/03/2020
02/27/2020 03/03/2020

SQL> select a.startdate, a.enddate,
  2    a.startdate + column_value - 1 dt
  3  from t1 a cross join
  4    table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
  5                        connect by level <= a.enddate - a.startdate + 1
  6                       ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
  7  order by dt;

STARTDATE  ENDDATE    DT
---------- ---------- ----------
01/31/2020 02/03/2020 01/31/2020
01/31/2020 02/03/2020 02/01/2020
01/31/2020 02/03/2020 02/02/2020
01/31/2020 02/03/2020 02/03/2020
02/27/2020 03/03/2020 02/27/2020
02/27/2020 03/03/2020 02/28/2020
02/27/2020 03/03/2020 02/29/2020
02/27/2020 03/03/2020 03/01/2020
02/27/2020 03/03/2020 03/02/2020
02/27/2020 03/03/2020 03/03/2020

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```

This is called a *row generator* technique (if you'd ever want too Google for it).

Answer (score 1):

Alternate solution

Creating table -

```
create table mytable(start_date date, end_date date);
```

Loading data -

```
insert into mytable values (to_date('01/31/2020','mm/dd/yyyy'),to_date('02/03/2020','mm/dd/yyyy'));
```

SQL to retrieve list of dates between the given date range -

```
select
   t.start_date + rownum -1 as dt,
   t.start_date,
   t.end_date
from
   all_objects, mytable t
where
   rownum <=
   t.end_date- t.start_date+1;
```

db fiddle - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7cd81f5892ad195b72ee1d22a3b44e2a

Answer (score 1):

For actual Oracle versions:

```
SELECT *
FROM t1,
     lateral(
           select level N,
                  t1.startdate+level-1 dt
           from dual
           connect by level <= t1.enddate - t1.startdate + 1
     );
```

or

```
SELECT 
  startdate,
  enddate,
  startdate+n as DT
FROM t1,
     xmltable('0 to xs:integer(.)' 
              passing cast(enddate-startdate as number)
               columns n int path '.'
             )
```

Full examples:

```
with t1
   AS (
      SELECT DATE '2020-1-31' AS startdate,
             DATE '2020-2-3' AS enddate
      FROM dual
      UNION
      SELECT DATE '2020-2-27' AS startdate,
             DATE '2020-3-3' AS enddate
      FROM dual
)
SELECT *
FROM t1,
     lateral(
           select level N,
                  t1.startdate+level-1 dt
           from dual
           connect by level <= t1.enddate - t1.startdate + 1
     );

with t1
   AS (
      SELECT DATE '2020-1-31' AS startdate,
             DATE '2020-2-3' AS enddate
      FROM dual
      UNION
      SELECT DATE '2020-2-27' AS startdate,
             DATE '2020-3-3' AS enddate
      FROM dual
)
SELECT 
  startdate,
  enddate,
  startdate+n as DT
FROM t1,
     xmltable('0 to xs:integer(.)' 
              passing cast(enddate-startdate as number)
               columns n int path '.'
             );
```